# Getting android shutdown reason in the code

Tags: android

I want to see the log of reasons why android shut down **in the code** before an activity is dead.
There will be many reasons for the android shutdown.

- user input(power button)
- low battery
- high degree
- shutdown command from other application
- and so on...

I tried forced shutdown(press power button and restart/power off) and saw `onStop()` is called and `onDestroy()` is not called.

My idea is that

1. make some kind of event hook for shutdown event
2. save every log in the `onStop()`

And so here are the questions

- Is it possible that saving logs in the `onStop()` before an activity is dead? (while shutdown proceeds)
- If possible, How can I get the reason(or status) for the shutdown **in the code**? (or at the JNI layer?)

Comment: "I want to see the log of reasons why android shut down in the code before an activity is dead" -- sorry, but Android does not supply this information to apps.

Comment: Then checking the log after shutdown is the only way?

Comment: I am uncertain what you mean by "the log". If you mean Logcat, you could perhaps do that using development tools. Android apps do not have access to all Logcat messages, and I do not know if there are shutdown-related messages that apps can access.